# Where does a question about Googling for stack overflow information belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

BACKGROUND: I wanted some help in figuring out how to Google for information about Stack Overflow itself. The specific information I was seeking was whether there was a feature in Stack Overflow to set a time zone so that reputation summary "days" would be in other than UTC. So the question I wanted ask is how to search information on Stack Overflow topics without getting overwhelmed by StackOverflow posts about the particular technical area (e.g. the gazillion StackOverflow posts dealing with time zones).

QUESTION: Where should a question about how to Google about Stack Overflow itself go and why?  Should it be on this site because it's about Stack Overflow?  Or is the topic of how to narrow Google searches something that belongs on SuperUser (or some other SE site)?

Comment: I think you can just search Stack Overflow meta site for this.

Comment: Are you suggesting this as a general alternative to using Google? Or is your comment limited to this specific topic concerning time zones and rep summaries (i.e. you think this has been covered had and can be found the MSO's search capability, such as it is)?

Comment: You can also ask the question itself on Meta Stack Overflow's chat. Questions in the form of "does anybody happen to know whether xyz" are fair game, especially when you've already searched to no avail. The answer to your question, however, is that AFAIK there is no such feature. SO's time zone is UTC, end of story. (Although that might be easy to change through a userscript)

Comment: Ahh indeed [Display absolute timestamps (in local time)](http://stackapps.com/q/2528)

Comment: Ok, I found and understand about time zones. I'd still appreciate an answer to the question under "QUESTION", completely independent of the example topic I used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe definitely belongs on Meta.

You can ask in a Meta Chat room like [the tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), or in a question on Meta proper.

That said - if your question really is "how do I use Google to find out x about Stack Overflow", you can just go ahead and ask the question itself.

If it's not totally trivial to find through a search, no one is going to give you a hard time about it.  If your question gets closed, you will most definitely be pointed to a duplicate.

Comment: So whereas a question about how to narrow Google searches to find out information about how a particular social networking site works without being inundated by posts _from_ that site would normally belong on SuperUser, the fact that I'm asking it in the context of the SO site makes it ok to ask here. Is that right?

Comment: @Peter I guess so, yeah. Although as said, I can't think of a scenario where asking about how to *search* really makes more sense than just asking the question itself. If you have a specific question in mind, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: I actually run into this phenomenon fairly frequently, whether it's Amazon or Facebook or Stack Overflow. If you want to learn about how a site with social networking capabilities handles some topic that _appears_ in many of its posts, it's generally tough filtering out posts that happen to include your search terms.